# how can I test if useState hook has been called with jest and react testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this component that I would like to test using Jest and React testing library :

```
export function GenericDivider({ stepsHeader = [], componentsFactory = [] }) {
   const [currentPage, changePage] = useState(0);
   const Component = componentsFactory[currentPage] || (() => <></>);

   return (
    <div className="container page__container">
          ...
                 <a
                   href="#"
                   key={name}
                   onClick={e => {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     if (index < componentsFactory.length) changePage(index);
                   }}
                   className={`nav-link ${currentPage === index && 'active'}`}
                 >
                   {name}
                 </a>
          ...
    </div>
   );
}

export default memo(GenericDivider);
```

I would like to test if changePage is called when I fire a click, is there a way i can do that using Jest and React testing library ?

I'm new to testing and I tried this but it doesn't seem to work

```
it('Should call changePage when button clicked', () => {
    const changePage = jest.fn();

    const { container } = render(
      <GenericDivider
        stepsHeader={['hamid', 'walid', 'khalid']}
        componentsFactory={[() => <></>, () => <></>, () => <></>]}
      />,
    );

    const button = container.querySelector('a');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    expect(changePage).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: how does `currentPage` affect rendering result?

Comment: @skyboyer it affects the CSS of the "a" tag by changing it's className, so i did my tests on the className before and after the click was fired.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Short answer: don't.

Testing an internal state variable very much goes against the philosophy behind react-testing-library. That lib is focused on the user, and what the user can see. The user has no concept of a state variable. Instead of testing that, think of the changes the user would see, and test for that. How is the UI updated? What different markup or styling is displayed? Consider how to test from the user's perspective, and you'll find your answers.

Check out react-testing-library's [Guiding Principles](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles) for more context. Then take a look through [this page](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query) for guidelines on which queries make the most sense for your use case.

Comment: @danerismycat : always believed in that principle as well. But recently a client rejected a solution cos test coverage was not 80% and it was pointing to useState line (if removed, coverage does get high). I wonder how you would handle such a request to have a coverge of ##% with hooks?

Comment: Get a new client?  It sounds like the problem is more with how test coverage is being determined. There's no need to test useState or the setter function it returns, as those are heavily tested as part of React. Is the method of calculating test coverage something you can adjust?

Comment: Without testing state, you aren't going to get a complete code coverage. Example: a component is set to be hidden by default (state variable set to false).  An onclick triggers logic to change state from false to true, thus display the component.  If you don't test that, you will have a hole in the code coverage.  I suppose there are other ways to test that, but a state change would help.

Comment: @cfnerd In that scenario: render the parent component, check that the child component isn't in the DOM, trigger a click, see if the child component is now in the DOM. If it is, your logic worked. The fact that a state variable was flipped is an implementation detail; testing that specifically doesn't add safety and only makes future refactors more annoying.

Comment: @dangerismycat if the component is getting rendered by setState then my logic won't work, because I can't use setState in the test. Or am I missing something? Is there any code example for such test?

Comment: @Wordpressor Correct — you _shouldn't_ call setState in the test. Users can't call setState, so your test shouldn't either. What causes setState to be called and to render your component? Trigger that user action, then test your component once it's rendered.